# Is my self.error() being overridden in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http

In my Google App Engine application, I have a handler with a method for PUT requests:

```
def postMethod(self, arg):
    response = do_backend_work(arg)
    if response.field is None:
        self.error(502)
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(
                {'message': "you've been a bad boy!"}))
    else:
        <deal with well-formatted requests here>
         .
         .
         .
```

However, when I do receive a request where `response.field` is `None` the request is returned as a 200. When I caught this error I inserted `raise Exception(str(self.response))` just before the `else` block as a sanity check and found this in the logs:

```
raise Exception(str(self.response))
Exception: 502 Bad Gateway
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 63

{"message": "you've been a bad boy!"}
INFO 2012-08-15 23:25:12,239 dev_appserver.py:2952] 
"PUT /url/resource HTTP/1.1" 200  -
```

is there something I'm missing about how App Engine is processing the request?

Answer (score 0):

After some rooting around, I figured out the problem. in my `do_backend_work` function, there was a rogue print statement which was hijacking the output stream! The moral of the story is: don't write to stdout on your Google App Engine back-end. I'm posting the question for the benefit of future generations.